# Loss functions reaching global minima

Tags: deep-learning

In Deep Learning  can we have train accuracy far less than 100% at the global minimum of the loss function?

I have coded a neural network in python to classify cats and non-cats. I chose a 2-layer network. It gave a train accuracy of 100% and a test accuracy of 70%.

When I increased the #layers to 4 the loss function is getting stuck at 0.6440 leading to train accuracy of 65% and a test accuracy of 34% for many random initializations.

We are expecting that our train accuracy on the 4-layer model should be 100%. But we are getting stuck at 65%. We are thinking that the loss function is reaching a global minimum since on many random initialization we are stagnating at a loss value of 0.6440. So, even though the loss function is reaching the global minimum, why is the train accuracy not reaching 100%? Hence our question,"In Deep Learning  can we have train accuracy non-zero at the global minimum of the loss function?"

Answer (score 0):

Sure this only depends on the capacity of the network. If you have only linear activations than the network is linear and the training accuracy is only 100% if the data is linear separable. For non-linear activation functions the capacity is not as clear. We do know in theory that a NN with a hidden layer is a universal function approximator given enough neurons (https://towardsdatascience.com/can-neural-networks-really-learn-any-function-65e106617fc6). So in theory it should be able to approximate any function arbitrarily well and therefore reach 100% train accuracy.

For your problem the main culprit is probably that you are stuck in some kind of local minima, which is just bad. Increasing the capacity should in theory never lead to a higher loss at the global optima. A lower loss does not necessarily mean that the accuracy is higher though.

Comment: The loss actually reduced to 0.00038 when we ran the 4-layer network for 2,00,000 iterations. But then the taining accuracy came down to 47%. I really cannot see why - "A lower loss does not necessarily mean that the accuracy is higher though". Can you please elaborate more on that?

Comment: Accuracy is a binary metric. Either your prediction is correct or it is not. This makes it inherently hard to train, due to the gradient not giving any information. Therefore, you optimize for some surrogate loss that is smooth and therefore lower at the decision boundary than far away. So the loss can improve a lot without changing the accuracy. It is also possible that some samples are now missclassified, but many other samples are now on the decision boundary and therefore have in total a lower loss than the higher accurate model.